# Kotlin like scope functions (let, also, apply, run) in Groovy

Tags: kotlin, groovy

I think the title speaks for itself - does Groovy have something like Kotlin scope functions?

```
obj.apply {
  foo()
  bar()
  baz()
}

// is the same as
obj.foo()
obj.bar()
obj.baz()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Groovy has `obj.with { }` method that allows you to do the same:

```
obj.with {
  foo()
  bar()
  baz()
}
```

There is also `obj.tap { }` variant (an equivalent of `obj.with(true) { }`) that does the same, but it returns the incoming object.

```
def newObj = obj.tap {
  foo()
  bar()
  baz()
}
```

---

<sup>Source: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/style-guide.html#_using_with_and_tap_for_repeated_operations_on_the_same_bean</sup>

Comment: Groovy `with` is like Kotlin `run`, and Groovy `tap` is like Kotlin `apply`.